# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in _decodeGhostPointEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c

After updating to iOS 8.4 (2 days back) my app keeps crashing with the error below. All I am trying to do is zoom in/out a mapView. How do I debug this ? The crash doesn't seem to be coming from any part of my code. In addition to crash below in Xcode console I see

```
uncompress returned -3
uncompress returned -3
uncompress returned -3


Thread 7Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)
#0  0x000000018e70c0ec in _decodeGhostPointEncoding ()
#1  0x000000018e55bc08 in -[GEOVectorTile(VMP4) _readPolygons:ofType:] ()
#2  0x000000018e55ac48 in -[GEOVectorTile(VMP4) _readPolygons:] ()
#3  0x000000018e553564 in -[GEOVectorTile(VMP4) _initWithVMP4:localizationData:tileKey:] ()
#4  0x000000018e55220c in -[GEOVectorTile initWithTileData:localizationData:tileKey:] ()
#5  0x000000018e551ee8 in -[GEOVectorTileDecoder decodeTile:forKey:] ()
#6  0x000000018e586dc4 in __49-[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:]_block_invoke419 ()
#7  0x0000000101580fd4 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#8  0x0000000101580f94 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#9  0x000000010158eb54 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#10 0x0000000101590248 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#11 0x000000019745d22c in _pthread_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.geo.tile-loader.0x14754bd80 (Thread 8)Queue : com.apple.geo.tile-loader.0x14754bd80 (serial)
#0  0x0000000101582700 in dispatch_async ()
#1  0x000000018e550b7c in -[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:] ()
#2  0x000000018e550608 in __40-[GEOTileServerRemoteProxy _handleTile:]_block_invoke ()
#3  0x0000000101580fd4 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#4  0x0000000101580f94 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#5  0x000000010158bdb8 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#6  0x00000001015842c4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#7  0x000000010158e5d4 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#8  0x0000000101590248 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#9  0x000000019745d22c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#10 0x000000019745cef0 in start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from GEOTileServerRemoteProxy (Thread 8)Queue : GEOTileServerRemoteProxy (serial)
#0  0x000000010158a0bc in _dispatch_barrier_async_f ()
#1  0x000000018e54fd08 in -[GEOTileServerRemoteProxy _handleTile:] ()
#2  0x000000018e54f9d4 in -[GEOTileServerRemoteProxy _handleEvent:fromConnection:] ()
#3  0x0000000197484ccc in _xpc_connection_call_event_handler ()
#4  0x0000000197482bd0 in _xpc_connection_mach_event ()
#5  0x0000000101581068 in _dispatch_client_callout4 ()
#6  0x0000000101584a38 in _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke ()
#7  0x000000010158c384 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#8  0x0000000101583eac in _dispatch_mach_invoke ()
#9  0x000000010158c384 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#10 0x00000001015842c4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#11 0x000000010158e5d4 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#12 0x0000000101590248 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#13 0x000000019745d22c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#14 0x000000019745cef0 in start_wqthread ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an exception coming from tile loader in iOS. I think this is a VectorKit framework issue. Don't think this is an app issue.

Comment: Yup that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably trying to access an object which has been deallocated.

You could try to debug with the `NSZombieEnabled`

Edit your scheme and enable it.

**Do not forget to disabled it, as it will not deallocate any objects while active.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did that. Did not get any zombie detected.